# keras segmentation InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,256,256,3] vs. [32,256,256,4]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to train a UNET in order to detect road damage after a natural disaster. My images are `256x256x3` and the masks are `256x256x1`. Pixels correspond to 4 classes: 0=background, 1=no damaged road, 2= damaged road and 3 = tree foliage obstructing the view. It looks something like this - (in the image only 3 classes can be seen):

[image: example tuple]

I have these images in folders with the following structure. I also have validation data in the same structure

```
-- train images
   -- img
      -- 1.png
      -- 2.png
-- train masks
   -- img
      -- 1_mask.png
      -- 2_mask.png
```

My train and validation data generators are the following

```
image_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 40, horizontal_flip = True,
                                          vertical_flip = True, zoom_range = 0.2,
                                          shear_range = 0.2,width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                          height_shift_range = 0.2)
mask_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 40, horizontal_flip = True,
                                          vertical_flip = True, zoom_range = 0.2,
                                          shear_range = 0.2,width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                          height_shift_range = 0.2)
validimg_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator()
validmask_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator()


image_array_gen = image_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_images_path, class_mode = None,
                                   target_size = (256,256), seed = 909)
mask_array_gen = mask_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_segs_path, class_mode = None,
                                   target_size = (256,256), seed = 909)
valid_image_array_gen = validimg_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory= val_images_path, class_mode = None,
                                   target_size = (256,256), seed = 909)
valid_mask_array_gen = validmask_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory= val_segs_path, class_mode = None,
                                   target_size = (256,256), seed = 909)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_array_gen, mask_array_gen)
valid_generator = zip(valid_image_array_gen, valid_mask_array_gen)
```

I understand that, as this is a segmentation problem, class_mode should be None. When I run the above cell the message `Found x images belonging to 1 classes.` appears, where x is the number of train and validation images I have in the subfolder "img". I think the error might be that I have my data in the "img" subfolders and keras think that all the images correspond to the class img, when actually there are 4 pixel classes. But if I put my data in the train images and train masks folders, I get the message `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.`

When I try training my model with `results = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(train_samples/batch_size),epochs=30, validation_data=valid_generator,validation_steps=int(valid_samples/batch_size))` I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,256,256,3] vs. [32,256,256,4]
     [[node gradient_tape/categorical_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-120-22f04a70298f>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_19597]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The code I used to define the model is at the end of this question. Note that if I change the final layer for `conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)` the error disappears and the training is done with no problem. This is also why I think the error might be that I have my data in the subfolder img, but what can I do to specify the model that the pixel classes are 4 without having this error?

## Model

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(4, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)
    
    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)
    return(model)


model = unet() 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy' ,metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

your train_images _path should be the path to the directory that contains the class sub directories. Same for the other directories you use in flow from directory.For example if you have a directory structure as shown below to classify dogs and cats

```
 c:
  ---train_images
     ---img
        --- cats
        --- dogs
then in flow from directory your path would be
r'c:\train_images\img'
```

flow from directory will create the classes cats and dogs

Comment: I understand that for image classification that is how it should be done, however, I'm trying semantic segmentation where all classes can occur in any image. So it's not so simple as having a folder for cats and another for dogs, one needs to classify each pixel as belonging to one or another class

Comment: OK misunderstood the question